# Swift 4: Cannot assign value of type '(_) -> Void' to type '(() -> ())?'

Tags: swift, closures

XCode 9, Beta 3. Swift 4.

```
    let button = JumpingButton(x: 0, y: 50, w: 150, h: 300) // JumpingButton: UIButton
    //Inside JumpingButton: // var clickAction: (() -> ())?


    button.clickAction = { (sender) -> Void in //Error line
        action()
        Sound.playSound(Sounds.Button)
    }
```

Getting the error: Cannot assign value of type '(_) -> Void' to type '(() -> ())?'

Comment: What type is `button`? It looks like the property expects a parameter-less closure. Can you try `button.clickAction = { action(); ... }`?

Comment: Edited. That worked, wanna provide an answer?

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `clickAction` expects a parameter-less function/closure. Simply change your code to:

```
button.clickAction = {
    action()
    Sound.playSound(Sounds.Button)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about the API of these functions (you never told us what they are), but here's what the error tells you:

> Cannot assign value of type

It's referring to parameter passing, which is a kind of "assignment"

> '(_) -> Void'

This is the type of the argument you gave to the parameter. It has some parameter of an unknown type `(_)`, and returns (`->`) `Void`.

> to type '(() -> ())?'

This is the type of argument that was expected for this parameter. It has no parameters (`()`), it returns (`->`) `Void` (`()`), and it's Optional (`(...)?`)

So the issue is that you're passing a closure with a parameter as an argument to a parameter that expects a parameter-less closure.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I resolved this way:

```
button.clickAction = { _ in
        action()
        Sound.playSound(Sounds.Button)
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: What's the difference with the accepted answer? Isn't it the same?

Comment: The difference is the " _ in " after the { . In my case that answer didn't compile

Comment: Exactly, my solution is for Swift 4, without the " _ in " I think it should work in Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your edit has your answer: the closure type is () -> (), but you're providing your closure a parameter.